# Is Nvidia GPU works when the load is bigger?

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-geforce

I have a laptop with Intel processor with an integrated video card and dedicated Nvidia card. How do I check which GPU is currently active, and how do I set Ubuntu to automatically switch to the Nvidia GPU when I'm doing something graphically intensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check and see which of the graphics solutions is in use by executing this command :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

The output shows something like :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: i915  

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

When it shows `Kernel driver in use: nvidia`, you are using the NVIDIA graphics adapter.

Use NVIDIA X Server Settings → PRIME Profiles to switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics.

Of course the NVIDIA graphics drivers and `nvidia-prime` have to be installed on the system.

Note: Automatically switching between the graphics cards is not supported on Linux systems.